# Word by word typeahead with AngularUI Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, typeahead, angular-ui-typeahead

Is it possible to use AngularUI Bootstraps typeahead directive to fetch suggestions only for the last word in a sentence?

E.g: if the user inputs "Red Ca" the suggestion should be something like "Car, Carousel, Candle" irrespective of what word came before "Ca"?

Of course, when the user selects "Car" the result should be "Red Car". It should not replace the whole content of the input.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 issues here to make it work :

1. Filter the suggestions according to the last word
2. Keep the beginning of the input as the user selects a value for the last word

1) is easily solved with a custom function to filter suggested values :

```
$scope.containsLastWord = function(state, viewValue) {
    var words = viewValue.split(" ");
    var currentWord = words[words.length - 1];
    return state.substr(0, currentWord.length).toLowerCase() == currentWord.toLowerCase();
}
```

And in your typeahead :

```
typeahead="name for name in states | filter:$viewValue:containsLastWord"
```

2) is more tricky because you cannot catch the select event before it changes the model. So I had to keep a track of the model old value, and change the model value after user selection :

```
var typeaheadLastValue = "";
$scope.$watch('selected', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    typeaheadLastValue = oldVal || "";
});

$scope.typeaheadOnSelect = function(item) {
    var words = typeaheadLastValue.split(" ");
    words[words.length - 1] = item;
    $scope.selected = words.join(" ");
}
```

And in your typeahead :

```
typeahead-on-select="typeaheadOnSelect($item)"
```

Plunker here : http://plnkr.co/edit/hutiNW5s58MfNBap0p1Z?p=preview

PS: This code doesn't handle the case when suggestions contain " "

Comment: It works great,but highlighting the matching text in the suggested list of words doesn't work for any other word except the first word in the input.